# Facebook likes for multi-language pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a site with 3 languages. Page url structure: `/{lang}/page/{id}`. For example `/en/page/2` or `/ru/page/2`. 
How to configure [facebook like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to have the same count of likes for the same page id ? If visitor liked `/en/page/2` I want to have the same count of likes on `/ru/page/2`

NOTE: Content is on the same language only UI is translated.

I have tried to use `data-href="/page/{id}"` and `<meta property="og:url" content="/{lang}/page/{id}">`  for each page. But when I click on the like button the like dialog disappears in 1 sec. and count of likes doesn't increase.

Comment: you can't. you have to do it from your side and have something like `/page/{id}` and then redirect based on geographical location. Or just provide `/page/{id}` as an entry point and allow users to change their language manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the like button to have the same count across languages the url for the 3 languages must be the same.

Te only solution is instead of having the language defined on your url with a uri segment is to use get parameter, this 3 examples:

```
/page/2?lang=ru

/page/2?lang=en

/page/2?lang=pt
```

For the facebook this 3 urls they're all the same because facebook strips down the get parameters